# How to form a sequence of consecutive numbers in Pytorch?

Tags: python, matlab, pytorch, sequence

How to convert the Matlab code

```
v = [1: n]
```

to pytorch?

Writing a whole loop for that seems inefficient.

Comment: Not a lot of downvotes here, but I'm guessing someone might think it's a slightly low effort question that has already been asked several times?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can directly use the `arange` method from Pytorch.

```
torch_v = torch.arange(1,n)
```

Reference: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=arange#torch.arange

Answer (score 3):

You form a sequence of consecutive numbers in python

```python
import numpy as np
v= np.arange(1,n)
```

if you want a torch tensor you can transform the numpy array like this:

```python
torch_v = torch.from_numpy(v)
```

Comment: This is not Pytorch yet though.